# How do I redirect if url ends with /text/text/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I have text behind the slash like `www.anitajohansen.nl/text` my site will work properly and show `www.anitajohansen.nl/?id=text`.

However when I put another slash with more text behind it like `www.anitajohansen.nl/text/text`, the images on my site mess up. I dont get how this causes to change the url of the image resources on my web page.

Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# If url ends with double forward slashes, will remove the latter one 
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"

# Dont redirect if the map/file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1 [L] 

# Redirect with everything after tld/ and put it inside ?id= 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?id=$1 [L]
```

**Edit:**

It only seems to "mess up" url's that go from the current directory, e.g. `./images/image1.png`. urls that go from the webroot (`/images/image1.png`) are fine and dont mess up.

Comment: Which `text` is supposed to be passed to `id` in this URL `www.anitajohansen.nl/text/text`? That's not a good example or are both `text` identical.

Comment: well I just dont want the images to get buggy when the user visits `www.anitajohansen.nl/anytexthere/anystringhere`

Comment: Again. Is the string that follows `...n1/` the one to be passed as a parameter to `id` or is the string in the last level of the URL structure, like `/anystringhere` in `www.anitajohansen.nl/anytexthere/anystringhere`?

Comment: The first thing you said is what I want, yes. Sorry for misunderstanding your question the first time. So anything that comes after `.nl/` must be passed to `id`

Comment: Okay. Which strings in the URL are fixed and which are dynamic? Is, for example, `anitajohansen.nl` always used as a domain?

Comment: anitajohansen.nl is always the domain, and ?id= is the only get parameter I have that identifies all of the dynamic pages I have

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)  ?id=$1 [L]` instead of the last rule.

Comment: @faa you forgot to close it with a $, but it works :) It gives me a 404 Object not found! page now. Is there a way to redirect them to `www.anitajohansen.nl/?id=defaultpage`?

Comment: You don't have to close it with `$`, leave it as it is and try again.

Comment: If I dont close it with `$`, the same thing happens as before. It messes up all the urls of my image resources.

Comment: That's another problem. Replace [L] with [R,L] so you can see the substitution URL to be able to make the necessary modifications. At this moment you will see the correct parameter is passed as the value of `id`, though.

Comment: @faa Thanks for that :P thats great for troubleshooting. But wtf! it works when I use [R,L] but not with just [L]

Comment: It should be the same as long as it is the same domain. Clear your browser's cache and check your script if it does not work with [L] only.

Comment: Well, It's definitely not the cache. by not working I ment it messes up the images again. With [R] on it only seems to get the first level part of the string after `.nl/` (which is what I want!), so `anitajohansen.nl/123/456` would redirect me to `anitajohansen.nl/?id=123`.

Comment: What does ([^/]+) do?

Comment: Matches only the first string after the domain and before any slash `/`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time dude. Do you have any clues to why it doesn't work without [R]?

Comment: That's why I did not answer the question. I don't have the whole picture and can't guess what the script that handles the final request does. But maybe now you have the tools to find out what's the problem as the parameter is being passed as expected.

Comment: @faa I've got a solution to my problem, and that is to modify all urls and make them start at the webroot. So it's /images/image1.jpg instead of ./images/image1.jpg. Do you think this is a good way of doing things? Sorry for asking so much but this is the first time ive been working with regex and .htaccess